# How can I format a float to 1 decimal place using trunc in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query. I am getting the result as `19`

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(19.00,1) FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(19.00,1)

        19
```

I need the results as `19.0` instead, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: @juergend: it's in the subject ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(19, '09.9') from dual;
```

see [Number Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570)

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to be using SQL*Plus you can format the column output directly:

```
SQL> COLUMN target FORMAT 09.9
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(19.00, 1) AS target FROM dual;

TARGET
------
  19.0
```

Voila...

Otherwise you would need to either set your IDE to dispaly numerics with a trailing decimal place or display it as a VARCHAR2:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(19.00, 1), '09.9')
  FROM dual;
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work too

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(19.00, 1),'00.9')   FROM dual;
```